# Why, in my Kali Linux, setting user-installed python3.9.5 to default python3 results in "permission denied: python3" or "python3: command not found"?

Tags: kali-linux, python, python3, alternatives

***BACKGROUND***

I am using a fresh installation of Kali Linux 2023.1, which has come with Python3.11.1. I need to install MobSF, which requires `python3` to correspond to version between python3.8 and python3.10.

So I decided to install pyenv and then version `3.9.5` via `pyenv install -v 3.9.5`. Then I executed `pyenv global 3.9.5`. Then I executed `python3 --version` and I got `permission denied`.

So I decided to use `update-alternatives` to make this newly installed `python3.9.5` as default. I executed the following command.

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/bin 1`

Then I executed `sudo update-alternatives --config python3` and it gave me

```
└─$ sudo update-alternatives --config python3
[sudo] password for user: 
There are 2 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                                      Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python3.11                        1         auto mode
  1            /home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/bin       1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.11                        1         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

and I entered **`1`**.

Now when I execute `sudo update-alternatives --config python3`, I get

```
└─$ sudo update-alternatives --config python3
[sudo] password for user: 
There are 2 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                                  Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/bin   1         auto mode
* 1            /home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/bin   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.11                    1         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

---

***QUESTION***

Now when I run `python3 -V`, I get

```
┌──(user㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ python3 -V       
zsh: permission denied: python3
                                                                                                                                                                                                    
┌──(user㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ sudo python3 -V                          
[sudo] password for user: 
sudo: python3: command not found
```

Now I don't know what to do. Please can someone guide?

---

***DETAILS FROM COMMENTS***

**Comment:** *So, is there a file there? You told the system to use /home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/bin/python3, does that exist? Is it executable?*

Following is the situation of /home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/bin/:

```
┌──(user㉿kali)-[~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/bin]
└─$ ls -al                      
total 116
drwxrwxrwx 2 user user  4096 Apr 28 07:10 .
drwxrwxrwx 6 user user  4096 Apr 28 03:24 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user     8 Apr 28 03:24 2to3 -> 2to3-3.9
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user   127 Apr 28 03:24 2to3-3.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user     7 Apr 28 03:24 idle -> idle3.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user     7 Apr 28 03:24 idle3 -> idle3.9
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user   125 Apr 28 03:24 idle3.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user     6 Apr 28 03:24 pip -> pip3.9
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user   255 Apr 28 03:24 pip3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user   255 Apr 28 03:24 pip3.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user     8 Apr 28 03:24 pydoc -> pydoc3.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user     8 Apr 28 03:24 pydoc3 -> pydoc3.9
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user   110 Apr 28 03:24 pydoc3.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user     9 Apr 28 03:24 python -> python3.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     root        25 Mar 13 08:18 python3 -> /etc/alternatives/python3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 17576 Apr 28 03:23 python3.9
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user  3111 Apr 28 03:24 python3.9-config
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 65392 Apr 28 03:24 python3.9-gdb.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user    16 Apr 28 03:24 python3-config -> python3.9-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user    16 Apr 28 03:24 python-config -> python3.9-config
```

As we can see that `python3` is a symlink which points to `/etc/alternatives/python3`. SO the following screenshot shows the situation of `/etc/alternatives/python3`

```
┌──(user㉿kali)-[/etc/alternatives/python3]
└─$ ls -al
total 116
drwxrwxrwx 2 user user  4096 Apr 28 07:10 .
drwxrwxrwx 6 user user  4096 Apr 28 03:24 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user     8 Apr 28 03:24 2to3 -> 2to3-3.9
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user   127 Apr 28 03:24 2to3-3.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user     7 Apr 28 03:24 idle -> idle3.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user     7 Apr 28 03:24 idle3 -> idle3.9
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user   125 Apr 28 03:24 idle3.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user     6 Apr 28 03:24 pip -> pip3.9
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user   255 Apr 28 03:24 pip3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user   255 Apr 28 03:24 pip3.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user     8 Apr 28 03:24 pydoc -> pydoc3.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user     8 Apr 28 03:24 pydoc3 -> pydoc3.9
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user   110 Apr 28 03:24 pydoc3.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user     9 Apr 28 03:24 python -> python3.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     root        25 Mar 13 08:18 python3 -> /etc/alternatives/python3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 17576 Apr 28 03:23 python3.9
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user  3111 Apr 28 03:24 python3.9-config
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 65392 Apr 28 03:24 python3.9-gdb.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user    16 Apr 28 03:24 python3-config -> python3.9-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user    16 Apr 28 03:24 python-config -> python3.9-config
```

Comment: So, is there a file there? You told the system to use `/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/bin/python3`, does that exist? Is it executable? Also, why are you changing the default `python3` for the whole system just to run a single tool? Can't you launch the tool with `/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/bin/python /path/to/tool`?

Comment: @terdon To your second question, No because the setup/installation of the tool requires the system to be running between python3.8 to python3.10. When I run `sudo ./setup.sh` _while the system's python is the first-priority-alternative_ , I get `[ERROR] MobSF dependencies require Python 3.8 - 3.10. You have Python version 3.11.2 or python3 points to Python 3.11.2`. And _when this python3.9.5 is the default alternative_ , running `sudo ./setup.sh` gives `[ERROR] python3 is not installed.`

Comment: Yes, don't do `sudo ./setup.sh`, do `sudo /home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/bin/python ./setup.sh`, that's what I mean. Please answer the other questions though. Don't answer in comments, add the info to your question.

Comment: @terdon About your first question I added details in the question as you advised.

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code. That said, are you saying that `/etc/alternatives/python3` is a directory and you have a python executable at `/etc/alternatives/python3/python3`? And why is `/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/bin/python3` a symlink to a directory instead of an executable? That's your main issue.

Comment: The command `python3` is picked up from `~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/bin`, and it's a symbolic link _to a directory_.  I don't know anything about how "alternatives" work or are supposed to work, but that's the source of the issue.

Comment: @Kusalananda terdon Thank you a lot, I don't know why it is a directory but I have messed up everything with too many installations of python and other changes. So I am doing a fresh installation of Kali Linux and then gonna go from there